# PredicateBuilder in Entity Framework Core with And & Or (in) clause n same query

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core, predicatebuilder

I am trying following to use in & and with in a same query for Entity Framework Core

```
// http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1, Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var invokedExpr = Expression.Invoke(expr2, expr1.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, invokedExpr), expr1.Parameters);
    }
```

}

I am trying scenario like

```
select * 
from transaction
where channel = 1
  and msisdn = '123123123'
  and service in (1, 2, 3)
```

or

```
select * 
from transaction
where channel = 1
  and msisdn = '123123123'
  and (service = 1 or service = 2 or service = 3)
    
    
private static Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> CreateSearchPredicate(TransactionSearchQuery search, User user)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Transaction>();           
           
    if (search.fk_channel_id > 0)
    {
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.fk_channel_id == search.fk_channel_id);
    }

    // msisdn
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search.msisdn))
    {
        predicate = predicate.And(p => p.msisdn == search.msisdn);
    } 

    if (search.transactionStates != null && search.transactionStates.Count > 0)
    {
        var predicateX = PredicateBuilder.True<Transaction>();//also tried with False

        foreach (var val in search.transactionStates)
        {
            predicateX = predicateX.Or(p => p.statusid == val);
        }

        predicate = predicate.And(predicateX);
    }          

    return predicate;
}
```

Please help me out - what changes do I need in my `CreateSearchPredicate` to run And & In (or clues simultaneously)

My db is mysql
My code in repository is like

```
 public override IEnumerable<Transaction> GetAll(Expression<Func<Transaction, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _context.Set<Transaction>().Include(h => h.ServiceOwner).Include(h => h.TransactionState).Include(h => h.OriginationValidationState).Include(h => h.CommunicationChannel).ThenInclude(h => h.Channel).Where(predicate).AsEnumerable();
            //return _context.Set<Transaction>().Where(predicate).AsEnumerable();
        }
```

Comment: The `Or` should definitely start with `false`, otherwise `true || something` is always `true` as you know. What was the problem when you "also tried with False"?

Comment: when i tried with false records doesn't get filtered on criteria

Comment: Also i get following error if i doesn't have any filter other then the one in OR i get error The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Transaction>
    .Where(t => True && False || Invoke(p => (Convert(p.statusid, Int32) == __val_0), t[Transaction])
    )' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Comment: @KamranShahid you don't need such code to combine conditions with `And`. Just append `Where` operations to the query, eg `if (idList!=null) { query=query.Where(x=>idList.Contains(x.Id))}`

Comment: @KamranShahid as for the repository code, how often do you need to load an entire graph, with all related entities? And given the fact that you can't use `Set<>` without first configuring the entities, why that instead of `_context.Transactions`? A "generic repository" on top of ORMs like EF Core is an *anti*pattern. The DbSet is the single-entity repository. A DbContext is a multi-entity unit of work

Comment: PS that final `AsEnumerable` isn't needed. And EF Core 5 introduces filtered Includes, which means `GetAll` will have to be replaced with something else if you want to load specific related entities only

Comment: Hi @PanagiotisKanavos. Can you please answer it with the changes needed in my code. i will try that and also accept your Answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know my solution is correct or not but i have use contains clause of list to resolve it within And predicate like following

```
            if (search.transactionStates != null && search.transactionStates.Count > 0)
            {
                predicate = predicate.And(p => search.transactionStates.Contains(p.statusid));
            }

            if (search.services != null && search.services.Count > 0)
            {

                predicate = predicate.And(p => p.fk_authentication_service_id.HasValue && search.services.Contains(p.fk_authentication_service_id.Value));
            }

            if (search.channels != null && search.channels.Count > 0)
            {
                predicate = predicate.And(p => p.fk_channel_id.HasValue && search.channels.Contains(p.fk_channel_id.Value));
            }
```